# How to add many GoogleMaps-Marker in cakePHP on a map

Tags: google-maps, cakephp, view, helper, cakephp-2.3

i've an little AddressDB with about 100 Addresses. So now i added the Helpper from https://github.com/marcferna/CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper.

I know how i can add on address to the view. But how do i add all the addresses to one map?

Can every help me please?

Many thanks in advance

Marcus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you adding a comma?

```
<?php $this->GoogleMap->addMarker("map_canvas",1, $atla['Atla']['street'].' '.$atla['Atla']['number'].', '.$atla['Atla']['zipcode'].' '.$atla['Atla']['city'],$atla['Atla']['name'])?> <?php endforeach; ?>
```

should probably be

```
<?php $this->GoogleMap->addMarker("map_canvas",1, $atla['Atla']['street'].' '.$atla['Atla']['number'].', '.$atla['Atla']['zipcode'].' '.$atla['Atla']['city'].','.$atla['Atla']['name'])?> <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But: How about http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/12/21/googlemapsv3-cakephp-helper/ ?
It is probably a more complete alternative.

As documented you can use

```
$this->GoogleMapV3->addMarker($options);
```

any many times as you want. I tried it with 500 and - although at this point you might want to switch to clusters - it still worked.

Comment: `The Problem is that now i get an error 'extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given`
This is my foreach `<?php foreach ($atlas as $atla): ?>
<?php $this->GoogleMap->addMarker("map_canvas",1, $atla['Atla']['street'].' '.$atla['Atla']['number'].', '.$atla['Atla']['zipcode'].' '.$atla['Atla']['city'],$atla['Atla']['name'])?>
<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: where is that extract() code? make sure whatever you are passing into extract() is an array.

Comment: Ok?! The Error will not show but also no marker
`<?php $this->GoogleMap->addMarker("map_canvas",1, array($atla['Atla']['street'].' '.$atla['Atla']['number'].', '.$atla['Atla']['zipcode'].' '.$atla['Atla']['city']),"testing")?>`
The add should look so
$this->GoogleMap->addMarker("map_canvas",1,"Neckarstraße 150A, 70190 Stuttgart", $marker_options)

Comment: oh, you did not properly read the article. you are using the wrong helper. note that my link has a totally different (and more complete) version of a google map helper. they are not related.

Comment: oh! Thanks. Now i'm at that point that i added `echo $this->Html>script('jquery');` to my default.ctp But i get the error `Map cannot be displayed!`

Comment: What does Firebug say? It should report the js error you encounter (if any). Also make sure the script is available and correctly included. And that your script() call is echoed to print the custom js of the markers.

Comment: Firefox is installed and firebug say "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/cakephp/js/jquery.js" Where do i get the file(s) in my js folder are 4 files (ga, html5-fallbacks, jquery.html5autofallback and jquery-1.9.1.min.js)

Comment: the include the right file - either rename your js file to "jquery.js" or include "jquery-1.9.1.min.js", not something in between...

Comment: Ok! Thanks for that! This map looks better :-) Now i try to add an marker from an address (not lat/long)

Comment: I dont think geocoding on demand is very resource-friendly and efficient. It is usually better to geocode a single time (in the backend) and persistently store the result for repetitive output. See http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/06/12/geocoding-with-cakephp/

Comment: I think so. But the first Step from me is to answer the question. Do we need lat / lng to drow an maps. Is it possible to drow via address on a map with this helper? And if yes, how? If not we have to update our DB with lat/lng infos...

Comment: not at the moment - as the linked article shows it is easier and way better to do this not on demand if possible. But I can take a look if that is possible in the near future.
If you really have to geocode on the fly stick to the original helper then.

Comment: Tanks for your help. My furture questions to this helper i will ask you over your blog.

Comment: Just to give you a quick heads up, I updated the helper to support at least basic "geocoding" capabilities. Still, I recommend using the backend-geocoding.